# How can I stop tkinter from refreshing until all shapes are drawn?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

My current python app displays on a tkinter canvas a few shapes.
At some point, the user presses a button which redraws the whole scene (there are layers of shapes).
The issue is that for a split of a second, you can see some of the bottom layers of the scene until the background is covered with all the shapes, which I want to avoid.
The question is, if there is a way to tell tkinter "stop refreshing the screen" and then after all shapes are added "now go and refresh as usual".

Comment: Tkinter doesn't update the display until you tell it to. There must be something in your code that is telling it to update the display. Without seeing your code, it's impossible for us to be any more specific.

Comment: Thank you, that gave me the right clue!
The issue seems to be connected to using "_thread", which I implemented to let the user use the UI while other stuff runs in the background, and this is somehow interferring with the tkinter update.